# Writing a predicate for Linq (2Sqlite)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, predicate

I have a following problem - limited ORM that imposes coupling of infrastructure to domain objects.

Please note this is a Windows Store Application and Reflection API differs from standard .Net

For example I have to manually implement navigational properties (relations in code) like this (assuming a I have a book aggregate with one-to-many child collection of chapters):

```
List<Chapters> Chapters
{get {return db.Query<Chapters>.Where(b => b.BookId == this.Id);}}
```

I want to reduce this coupling be the means of generic extension method, that will retrieve child entities for parent, like

```
  IEnumerable<T> GetChildren<TParent,TChild>(this TParent parent) 
                                                   where TParent, TChild : Entity
```

I can assume that all Entities have an Id primary key property and foreign key is composed of Parent entity name and Id ("BookId")

How do I implement a predicate for db.Query.Where Linq method in this extension method, assuming *this* parameter is parent entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like so (simplified version):

```
    public static TChild GetHierarchyChild<TParent, TChild>(this TParent parent)
        {
            var pType = typeof(TParent);
            var chType = typeof(TChild);

            var chPropInfo = pType
                                  .GetProperties()
                                  .FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType == chType);
            if (chPropInfo == null)
            {
                return default(TChild);

            }

            return (TChild)chPropInfo.GetValue(parent);
        }

    public class A
    {
        public IEnumerable<B> Bs
        {
            get
            {
                return new[] { new B(1) };
            }
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public B(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public int Id { get; protected set; }
    }
```

an example:

```
var a = new A();
var bs = GetHierarchyChild<A, IEnumerable<B>>(a);
bs.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me but unfortunately Sqlite-Net does not support expressions of this type in its Linq2Db implementation. It crashes on the last statement. I will have to rewrite this part to SQL.

```
        private const string keyName = "Id";

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<TChild>> GetChildrenAsync<TParent, TChild>(this TParent parent)
        where TParent : Entity
        where TChild : Entity, new()
    {
        var parentType = typeof (TParent);
        var parentName = parentType.GetTypeInfo().Name;
        var parentKeyValue = (int)parentType.GetRuntimeProperty(keyName).GetValue(parent);
        var foreignKeyName = String.Format("{0}{1}", parentName, keyName);
        var childProperty = typeof(TChild).GetRuntimeProperty(foreignKeyName);

        var connection = DbConnection.Current;
        var query = connection.Table<TChild>().Where(c => (int)childProperty.GetValue(c) == parentKeyValue);
        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
```